# AngularJS $compile + Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm writing my component with AngularJS 1.5 and typescript and the component looks like this:

```
@Component('taskbaseApp', 'taskk', {
  templateUrl: '/components/directives/taskk/taskk-directive.html',
  bindings: {
    task: "<", // One Way Binding
    settings: "<" // One Way Binding
  }
})

class Taskk {

  public task: string;
  public settings: string;
  static $inject: string[] = ['Utils', '$compile'];

  constructor(private Utils, private $compile) {
    console.log('hi');
  }

  public sayHello() {
    console.log('hi')
  }
}
```

How would I go about using `$compile`? For example if I wanted `$compile("<div>hi</div>");`, where do I put that and how do I get it to the "scope"?

Comment: I guess you can inject `$scope` dependency in `$inject` array & use it to `$compile` DOM

Comment: could you please provide the exact code? thanks a lot